# Injection issue with spring boot 3 and acitiviti engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, activiti, camunda, bpmn

I started a spring boot 3.2 project, where I added the activiti-engine dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And I see this error:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'RuntimeService' type found

When I try to inject the `RuntimeService` in order to call the `startProcessInstanceById` method.

I saw many questions similar to mine, but still I couldn't figure out the best alternative or solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'RuntimeService' type found

This error typically arises when **Spring Boot cannot locate** a bean of `RuntimeService` type to inject into the dependent class.

So first ensure that `RuntimeService` bean is properly configured and available for injection.

Then:

- You can explicitly define `RuntimeService` bean in your Spring configuration class using `@Bean` annotation.

```
 @Configuration
 public class ActivitiConfig {
 
     @Bean
     public RuntimeService runtimeService() {
         return processEngine().getRuntimeService();
     }
 }
```

- Or add the `@Service` annotation to the `RuntimeService` class to make it a Spring-managed bean.

```
 @Service
 public class RuntimeService {
     // Service implementation
 }
```